# Display ticket remaining time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am programming small page and I want to display expiration time of authentication ticket. I mean not the end, but remaining time. Current code is follows:

```
    DateTime cas = (DateTime)ticket.Expiration.Date;
    DateTime cas1 = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime cas2 = cas1.Subtract(cas);
```

However, VS says "Cannot implicitly convert system.timespan into system datetime".
 Pls help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substract method returns a timespan, not a Datetime. Try this :

```
  Timespan cas2 = cas.Subtract(cas1);
```

[edit] following the comments, the code that should works is simply :

```
TimeSpan remaining = ticket.Expiration.Substract(DateTime.Now);
```

You don't have to case Expiration, as it's a [DateTime property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.expiration.aspx).

Comment: it works, but the time is increasing (and expiration time is set to 1 minute in web.config)

Comment: The time is not increasing, but is negative. Reverse the substraction : `cas.Substract(cas1)`. I update my answer in this way

Comment: Are you sure you want to call the .Date property ? It returns the truncated date (truncated to the beginning of the day). Shouldn't your code be `ticket.Expiration` instead of `ticket.Expiration.Date` ?

Comment: solved with  TimeSpan cas = ticket.Expiration.TimeOfDay;
        TimeSpan cas1 = (TimeSpan)DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;  thanks

Comment: this won't work if the expiration time is not the same day as today. Check my edit for a full code sample

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator overloading. The type returned by subtracting one DateTime from another is a TimeSpan:

```
TimeSpan remainingTime = ticket.Expiration - DateTime.Now;
```